# Can't connect to Django database in Heroku

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django application in Heroku and connect it to a database using [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url%20dj-database-url). The app runs fine locally (with `python manage.py runserver`) but both the `heroku local web` command and the Heroku deployment fail with the message:

```
9:47:06 PM web.1 |  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

However, when I go into Heroku's shell and try to install the package, it says that the requirement is already satisfied

```
~ $ pip install dj-database-url
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url in ./.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

As a side note, I have another module called `django_hosts` which I use and doesn't have any problems. Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.1
django-hosts==3.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2018.5
```

And here are the lines in `production.py` settings file that uses `dj_database_url`:

```
import dj_database_url
...
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

I don't know if it helps, but here are my installed apps:

I

```
NSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # third party
    'django_hosts',

    # custom apps
    'analytics',
    'shortener',
]
```

I thought that maybe I need to add `dj_databse_url` underneath `django_hosts`, but it didn't work.

If you need any more information, please let me know in the comments. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue was to add the dependency to my Pipfile and then re-generate Pipfile.lock. This was necessary despite requirements.txt already having the dependency listed.

Comment: Hi! I don't have a Pipfile.lock file. I see that there's a package called pipenv which generates that. I have been using pyenv until now, but I'll give a try to the one you said.